# can't create stl containers of type AABB tree in CGAL

Tags: c++, containers, computational-geometry, cgal

I am trying to create a STL map of type `map<int,CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits>>` (map of [AABB tree's](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/AABB_tree/index.html)) when I try to assign a value to the map, for example (this code is only for demonstration purposes):

```
//CGAL includes begin
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_incremental_builder_3.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive.h>
//CGAL includes end
/*
 * CGAL typedef's for initialization
 */
typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double>                          K;
typedef K::FT                                                   FT;
typedef K::Point_3                                              Point_3;
typedef K::Segment_3                                            Segment;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K>                                   Polyhedron;
typedef Polyhedron::HalfedgeDS                                  HalfedgeDS;
typedef Polyhedron::Vertex_const_iterator                       Vertex_const_iterator;
typedef Polyhedron::Facet_const_iterator                        Facet_const_iterator;
typedef Polyhedron::Halfedge_around_facet_const_circulator      Halfedge_around_facet_const_circulator;
typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<Polyhedron>    Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive>                         Traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits>                                 Tree;
typedef Tree::Point_and_primitive_id                            Point_and_primitive_id;
//end of typedef's

BuildMesh<HalfedgeDS> mesh(V, F);
polyhedron.delegate( mesh);
myMap[someInt] = Tree(polyhedron.facets_begin(),polyhedron.facets_end(),polyhedron);
```

I get the following error:

> error C2248: 'CGAL::AABB_tree< AABBTraits >::operator =' : cannot
>   access private member declared in class 'CGAL::AABB_tree< AABBTraits>'

I tried looking in the source code of CGAL and found in CGAL\AABB_tree.h the following lines:

```
private:
        // Disabled copy constructor & assignment operator
        typedef AABB_tree<AABBTraits> Self;
        AABB_tree(const Self& src);
        Self& operator=(const Self& src);
```

this means that the copy and assignment constructors are private, thus it's not possible to create
stl containers of type Tree.

I tried to use pointers instead I changed my map to `map<int,CGAL::AABB_tree < Traits > *  >`
and tried:

```
BuildMesh<HalfedgeDS> mesh(V, F);
polyhedron.delegate( mesh);
myMap[someInt] = new Tree(polyhedron.facets_begin(),polyhedron.facets_end(),polyhedron);
```

but then it crashed my code.

Is there any way around it so it will be possible to create an STL container of this type?

**UPDATE 14/3/2014**

I tried using Drop's solution as suggested  but I got the following error:

> error C2248: 'CGAL::AABB_tree::AABB_tree' : cannot access
>   private member declared in class 'CGAL::AABB_tree'

**UPDATE 17/3/2014**

Here is a sample code that doesn't compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <CGAL/Simple_cartesian.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_tree.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_traits.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive.h>
using std::map;

typedef CGAL::Simple_cartesian<double> K;
typedef K::FT FT;
typedef K::Point_3 Point;
typedef K::Segment_3 Segment;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<K> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::AABB_face_graph_triangle_primitive<Polyhedron> Primitive;
typedef CGAL::AABB_traits<K, Primitive> Traits;
typedef CGAL::AABB_tree<Traits> Tree;
typedef Tree::Point_and_primitive_id Point_and_primitive_id;
int main()
{
    map<int,Tree> myMap;
    Point p(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Point q(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    Point r(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    Point s(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    Polyhedron polyhedron;
    polyhedron.make_tetrahedron(p, q, r, s);

    // here i get the error
    myMap.emplace(
        std::piecewise_construct,
        std::forward_as_tuple(1),
        std::forward_as_tuple(polyhedron.facets_begin(), polyhedron.facets_end(),polyhedron));
    myMap[1].accelerate_distance_queries();
    // query point
    Point query(0.0, 0.0, 3.0);
    // computes squared distance from query
    FT sqd = myMap[1].squared_distance(query);
    std::cout << "squared distance: " << sqd << std::endl;
    // computes closest point
    Point closest = myMap[1].closest_point(query);
    std::cout << "closest point: " << closest << std::endl;
    // computes closest point and primitive id
    Point_and_primitive_id pp = myMap[1].closest_point_and_primitive(query);
    Point closest_point = pp.first;
    Polyhedron::Face_handle f = pp.second; // closest primitive id
    std::cout << "closest point: " << closest_point << std::endl;
    std::cout << "closest triangle: ( "
              << f->halfedge()->vertex()->point() << " , " 
              << f->halfedge()->next()->vertex()->point() << " , "
              << f->halfedge()->next()->next()->vertex()->point()
              << " )" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly "crashed"? You use a debugger, don't you? Alternative to (smart)pointers can be adding a level of indirection: put your data to a wrapper class and define copy semantics to it, then make a container of wrappers.

Comment: I am writing a mex file so debugging is hard. i did put the data in a wrapper class but it's impossible to write copy semantics because the AABB tree doesn't have copy semantics so i couldn't duplicate it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::map::emplace()` method, std::pair's piecewise constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) and [perfect forwarding](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward), to construct your non-copyable and non-assignable data in-place:

```
myMap.emplace(
    std::piecewise_construct,  // disambiguation hint
    std::forward_as_tuple(someInt),  // perfectly forward arguments to key_type constructor
    std::forward_as_tuple(polyhedron.facets_begin(), polyhedron.facets_end(),
        polyhedron)); // perfectly forward arguments to value_type constructor
```

Solution is very verbose, but fully C++11 standard compliant.

Working example: [Coliru Viewer](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed469464f57bd21f)

**Edit:** 
Use `std::make_tuple` instead of `std::forward_as_tuple` if your compiler does not support it (`#include <tuple>`).

**Edit2:**

After reviewing code snipped added, I found that errors was triggered not by `map::emplace` method (can be easily verified by commenting it out), but by later usage of `map::operator[]`. Internally, `map::operator[]` uses `map::insert` (check it's source code). Just use [`map::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/at) instead to fix issues. Example:

```
FT sqd = myMap.at(1).squared_distance(query);
```

Note, that `map::at()` throws exception if key not found. You could be interested (depending on performance demands) in  reassuring key by checking with [`map::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) before accessing to value.

Note also, that you are receiving verbose warnings, because of CGAL internals usage of "unsafe" string functions. They are not errors and could be disabled by adding `-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` compiler flag.

<sup>Hope it helps. Happy coding!</sup>

Comment: i get the following error when i use your method:

error C2248: 'CGAL::AABB_tree<AABBTraits>::AABB_tree' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CGAL::AABB_tree<AABBTraits>'

Comment: Check your code: is error really points to `emplace()`? Check your compiler version: is it supports C++11? I've tested with MSVC 2013 and GCC 4.8 (see working example with imitation of non-copyable and non-assignable type)

Comment: I use visual studio 2012 so it supports c++ 11. the error occurs only when i try to assign a AABB Tree value to the map. the problem is with CGAL i think. i have a suspicion the it's actually a bug in CGAL... the problem occurs when you use the Tree constructor like Tree(...) instead of Tree a(...) (which works fine).

Comment: @DontCareBear I did not get it. You've indicated that assignment operator and copy constructor is private, so you cannot `myMap[someInt] = Tree(...)`. Then I've proposed you a solution with `myMap.emplace()` instead (with no assignment or copying). But you still assigning somewhere and getting error unrelated to `map::emplace()` stuff. Where I get wrong?

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong. the error occurs only when I add the AABB tree to the map with the syntax you proposed:    map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,std::forward_as_tuple(idCount),
std::forward_as_tuple(polyhedron.facets_begin(), polyhedron.facets_end(),
       polyhedron)); 

when I remove this line (and don't add the AABB Tree to the map) the error disappears. it means that even this syntax that don't use assignment or copy operators still uses something private from the AABB Tree class.

Comment: @DontCareBear So strange. It works perfectly for me. Can you upload your source file so I can take a look? Add compiler's full version too (write `cl` in VS command prompt).

Comment: did you try it with cgal's AABB tree? the problem is caused specifically because the compiler can't access somthing in the AABB tree when using your syntax.

Comment: @DontCareBear yes, I tried it with VS2012 and VS2013 before posting the code.

Comment: I will add sample code that doesn't work for me in the original question.

Comment: @DontCareBear Okay, I've edited answer. Problem was with `map::operator[]`.